# how to change label color on click?

Tags: java, user-interface, gwt, onclick, label

if I try to to run the for loop till 10 it is keep printing the same label 10 times. and if I change till function.size and it will print number of function times.
color is changing only inside the same labels, not effecting the other labels. 
I have variables are string that I am printing on label,how should I assign the string to ArryList?
final List labels = new ArrayList();

```
                for(int k = 0; k <=1; k++) {
                     final Label label = new Label(FDTO.getFunctionName());

                   // final  Label functionLabel = new Label(FDTO.getFunctionName());
                    label.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {     

                    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

                         for(Label otherLabel  : labels)
                             otherLabel.getElement().getStyle().setColor("black");
                        // functionLabel.getElement().getStyle().setColor("red");
                        label.getElement().getStyle().setColor("red");
                        checkChild(FDTO.getFunctionCode(), functions, qaDTO, val);
                    }
                });

                    labels.add(label);


                    childPanel.add(label);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `ClickHandler` you just need to set all other labels` color back to default (black?).

```
otherLabel.getElement().getStyle().setColor("black");
```

If there are many *other labels* you should consider keeping them in a `List`. Please, try this little example:

```
final List<Label> labels = new ArrayList<Label>();

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    final Label label = new Label("Hello " + i);
    label.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            // change all labels color back to default
            for(Label otherLabel : labels)
                otherLabel.getElement().getStyle().setColor("black");

            // change current label color 
            label.getElement().getStyle().setColor("red");
        }
    });

    // add to list
    labels.add(label);

    RootPanel.get().add(label);
}
```

Comment: when I try to put the getfunctionName(database variable that need to be print on label) in the list. it gives me the error. change string to int or remove parameters. I tried this code but it is repeating the label itself 2 times and which those two label functionality working fine.

Comment: how can I post my comment again? so you can see what I did. In the comments it says it is too long

Comment: sorry not 10 times. it prints 2 time.

Comment: I used the `for` loop just to demonstrate how it works with many labels. You should fill the list with your function labels. In the `ClickHandler` restore the default color of all labels and change the color of the clicked label.

Comment: thanks for your help, but where should i add my functions?  I am not understanding. I want my loop runs till I have functions. but is is repeating one  variable number of times. Am I doing something wrong?